# Android Kotlin - app crash RuntimeException NullPointerException in MainActivity.I

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In the gogole play console I see that some of the users with android 10, 11 and 12 are getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4031)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4197)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2434)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8633)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:567)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1133)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.domain.bla.MainActivity.I (MainActivity.java:30)
  at com.domain.bla.MainActivity.setNavi (MainActivity.java)
  at com.domain.bla.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8282)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8262)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1329)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4005)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4197)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2434)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8633)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:567)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1133)
```

I don't have the function i() in MainActivity or anywhere in the app, maybe in one of the libraries but not from me.

I have testing devices with android 11 and 12 but can't reproduce this error, everything works as it should on those.

Posting the whole MainActivity would be way too much sicne it's over 1300 lines.

This is the `setNavi` function:

```
private fun setNavi(gal: String){

    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, binding.drawerLayout, binding.contentMain.toolbar, 0, 0
    )

    binding.drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()
    binding.navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

    if(gal == "latest"){
        binding.navView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_latest)
    }else{
        binding.navView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_top)
    }

    binding.navView.itemIconTintList = null

    binding.contentMain.btnOpenSearch.setOnClickListener {
        binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START, true)
        val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, SearchInput::class.java)
        this.startActivity(i)
    }


    val headerLayout = binding.navView.getHeaderView(0) // to set stuff in menu
    //headerLayout.btnUpload.setOnClickListener {

    val btnUpload: ConstraintLayout = headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload)
    btnUpload.setOnClickListener {
        if(prefs.getLong("userid", 0) == 0.toLong()){
            val i = Intent(this, Login::class.java)
            this.startActivity(i)

        }else{
            binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START, true)

            val i = Intent(this, Upload::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
        }
    }

    setHeader()
}
```

maybe the problem is in there?

Comment: The stacktrace says the problem in the ``I`` method is at line 30 in ``MainActivity``, so I'd check what's going on there!

Comment: the line 30 in MainActivity is: import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer! As I said I don't have a method i. I think it's from a file that is generated in the background or something

Comment: One of your method names has been changed to I by obfuscation, and the line numbers are probably not trustworthy either. Check all the calls you’ve made to Java functions and properties and see if there’s one that doesn’t have nullability annotations where you’ve assigned a return value to a non-nullable property or variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your app has minify enabled in your release build, it obfuscates and optimizes your code, therefore will show things on different lines. You can have a more assertive stacktrace if you provide google play the txt file provided by your minify method. Read: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#decode-stack-trace

Comment: "You can have a more assertive stacktrace if you provide google play the txt file provided by your minify method" but how? I don't find the part how to do that in all the jabbering in the docs

Comment: @EduardUnruh: The documentation linked to in the answer, in turn, links to [Google Play's own documentation on the subject](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633). Alternatively, adjust your Proguard configuration file to add `-dontobfuscate`, to tell ProGuard/R8 to not rename your methods, so your Play stack traces are readable more directly.

Comment: But where exactly do I have to add it? proguard-android-optimize.txt or proguard-rules.pro or both? I can't test around because I can't reproduce the error on my devices, only some users are getting this error

Comment: Put it in proguard-rules.pro. Then when you build your app, copy the `mapping.txt` file out of the `build/outputs` directory (something like that, I’m going off memory). In the Google Play console where you upload your app, you can attach the mapping file as your retrace file for the apk when you upload it. Sadly, it is too late to deobfuscate your previously uploaded build of you didn’t save the mapping file from when you built that version.

Comment: I know what the problem was now before I did the proguard stuff, mentioning minifyenabled made me find the real cause for the problem that's why I check the answer, it was using gson! I just don't understand why it happens only on few devices then, android is a total shithole! Thanks to you all! I will also use the stuff with proguard for future debugging